# Creating a file name using variables in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write out to a file, where the file name is created from a variable(the name + the user id + the date and time + file extension).

I have read various things on Stackoverflow which I have based my code off.

```
my $windowsfile = "winUserfile-$User_ID-$datetime.csv";
open winUserfile, ">>", $windowsfile) or die "$!";
print winUserfile "User_ID, Expression\n";
close winUserfile;
```

I would assumed this would work, but I am getting a syntax error. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: The idea is just fine, but you have a closing paren without a matching opening one. Either add a paren or remove one, either way will work.

Comment: You might also want to use `">"` instead of `">>"`, as to not append to but to replace the file if debugging for the same output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line has a close-paren without the preceeding open:

```
open winUserfile, ">>", $windowsfile) or die "$!";
```

You likely want to open it first

```
open(winUserfile, ">>", $windowsfile) or die "$!";
```

Or just not bother with them entirely here, as they're optional in this case

```
open winUserfile, ">>", $windowsfile or die "$!";
```

---

Also, it's bad style to use a bareword filehandle, as this creates becomes global. Better to use a lexical one:

```
open my $winUserfile, ">>", $windowsfile or die "$!";
print $winUserfile "User_ID, Expression\n";
```

You don't then need to close it; the close will be automatic when the `$winUserfile` variable goes out of scope.

Comment: I have tried to use this solution I am still getting an invalid argument error; would you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I like using the `IO::All` module for file io.

```
use IO::All

my $windowsfile = "winUserfile-$User_ID-$datetime.csv";
io($windowsfile) > "User_ID, Expression\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my $windowsfile = "winUserfile-$User_ID-$datetime.csv";
open (winUserfile, ">>$windowsfile") or die "$!";
print winUserfile "User_ID, Expression\n";
close winUserfile;
```